# How to integrate an Xfce panel indicator into the Unity panel?

Tags: unity, xfce, indicator

Coming from the question [Is there a tray icon indicator to quickly access recent files in Ubuntu 16.04 Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/803869/is-there-a-tray-icon-indicator-to-quickly-access-recent-files-in-ubuntu-16-04-un), the related question occurred how to integrate an Xfce panel indicator into the Ubuntu Unity panel.

For example, how would one integrate the [Xfce Panel Places Indicator](http://goodies.xfce.org/projects/panel-plugins/xfce4-places-plugin) into the Unity panel?